# SVG- path clipping using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to clip the path using JavaScript. I have tried the below code.

```html
   <svg width="900" height="600">
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path d="M 0 464 L 0 293.8666666666667 C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667 L 834 464" />
        </clipPath>
        <path d="M 0 464 L 0 293.8666666666667 C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667 L 834 464" fill="red" opacity="0.8" />
        <path d="M 0 293 L 0 139.19999999999996 C 92.6666666666456 107.06370370370374 185.3333333332912 74.92740740740744 278 69.60000000000001 C 370.6666666666456 64.27259259259263 463.33333333329125 85.75407407407415 556 108.2666666666667 C 648.6666666666456 130.77925925925928 741.3333333332912 154.322962962963 834 177.86666666666665 L 834 340.2666666666667 M 0 293.8666666666667  C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667" stroke="red" fill="green" opacity="0.7"/>
    </svg>
```

This clips the path except the red color path. I want to clip the green color path rendered on red one. Is it possible to clip that?

Comment: Your request is not clear. Can you try again to explain what want please?  Also, you've defined a clip path, but you have not assigned it to anything.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I want to place path in green color exactly over the path in red color. I have tried to achieve that using cilp-path for red color path. It is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```html
<svg width="900" height="600">
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path d="M 0 464 L 0 293.8666666666667 C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667 L 834 464" />
        </clipPath>
        <path d="M 0 464 L 0 293.8666666666667 C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667 L 834 464" fill="red" opacity="0.8" />
        <path d="M 0 293 L 0 139.19999999999996 C 92.6666666666456 107.06370370370374 185.3333333332912 74.92740740740744 278 69.60000000000001 C 370.6666666666456 64.27259259259263 463.33333333329125 85.75407407407415 556 108.2666666666667 C 648.6666666666456 130.77925925925928 741.3333333332912 154.322962962963 834 177.86666666666665 L 834 340.2666666666667 M 0 293.8666666666667  C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667" stroke="red" fill="green" opacity="0.7"
              clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
    </svg>
```

**Update**

The simplest solution is to construct your green path properly.  Your original green path consisted of two sub-paths:

1. One started at left and went up over the top and down the right.
2. The second started on the left and followed the top of the red curve over.

[image]

Sub-paths are filled separately, so you were actually getting two green shapes. Both of which overlapped the top of the red shape.

The solution is to reverse the second sub-path (so it goes from right to left). 
 Then use it to complete the first green shape so it goes around the red shape, instead of across it.

[image]

```html
  <svg width="900" height="600">
        <path d="M 0 464 L 0 293.8666666666667 C 92.6666666666456 251.59111111111108 185.3333333332912 209.31555555555556 278 201.06666666666666 C 370.6666666666456 192.8177777777778 463.33333333329125 218.59555555555556 556 247.46666666666673 C 648.6666666666456 276.33777777777783 741.3333333332912 308.3022222222222 834 340.2666666666667 L 834 464" fill="red" opacity="0.8" />
        <path d="M 0 293 L 0 139.19999999999996 C 92.6666666666456 107.06370370370374 185.3333333332912 74.92740740740744 278 69.60000000000001 C 370.6666666666456 64.27259259259263 463.33333333329125 85.75407407407415 556 108.2666666666667 C 648.6666666666456 130.77925925925928 741.3333333332912 154.322962962963 834 177.86666666666665 L 834 340.2666666666667 C 741 308 648 276 556 247 C 463 218 370 192 278 201 C 185 209 92 251 0 293 Z" stroke="red" fill="green" opacity="0.7"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: No not like this. I want to exactly clip the area placed above the first path( path in red color). So Second path(green color) will be exactly placed above the red one.

Comment: So there is no overlap you mean?  The green will be an arch that sits exactly to the north of the red one?

Comment: Yes. That what i want to achieve. I can't place green arch behind the red arch. Because if we set opacity for path, then green arch behind the red arch will be visible. How to achieve this?